# How to debug python dataflow beam.io.WriteToBigQuery

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

I currently have a python dataflow job whose end sink is a PCollection write to BigQuery. It's failing with the following error:

```
Workflow failed. Causes: S01:XXXX+XXX+Write/WriteToBigQuery/NativeWrite failed., BigQuery import job "dataflow_job_XXXXXX" failed., BigQuery job "dataflow_job_XXXXXX" in project "XXXXXX" finished with error(s): errorResult: Error while reading data, error message: JSON table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 19; errors: 1
```

To get a more detailed error report I'm then running:

```
bq --format=prettyjson show -j dataflow_job_XXXXXX
```

which displays something like (there are a bunch of errors this is just one of them):

```
{

    "location": "gs://XXXXX/XXXXXX/tmp/XXXXX/10002237702794672370/dax-tmp-2019-02-05_20_14_50-18341731408970037725-S01-0-5144bb700f6a9f0b/-shard--try-00d3c2c24d5b0371-endshard.json",

    "message": "Error while reading data, error message: JSON table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 11; errors: 1. Please look into the errors[] collection for more details.",                                          

    "reason": "invalid"

  },
```

I then go looking for the particular shard to see what PCollection row is in error and what I need to do to either filter these rows or fix a bug of mine:

```
gsutil ls gs://XXXXX/XXXXXX/tmp/XXXXX/10002237702794672370/dax-tmp-2019-02-05_20_14_50-18341731408970037725-S01-0-5144bb700f6a9f0b/-shard--try-00d3c2c24d5b0371-endshard.json
```

But that command returns:

```
CommandException: One or more URLs matched no objects.
```

What are the best practices for debugging jobs (which takes multiple hours btw)? My thought right now is to write the PCollection to GCS in a non-temp location in JSON format and try to ingest it myself.

Comment: Use a smaller dataset size, and use the Direct/Local Runner on your own machine to debug, Would this be possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your type of error, I do the following:

1. Use a Json check tool to list records with errors.
2. Run Cloud Dataflow locally.
3. Add a pipeline step to validate each Json record and remove the bad entries from the pipeline. Use a dead letter file using side output OR log the bad records for debugging.

This article might give you some ideas for handling invalid inputs.

[Handling Invalid Inputs in Dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/handling-invalid-inputs-in-dataflow)

Comment: Yeah so I ended up doing 1) by accident. In my process of doing "write the PCollection to GCS in a non-temp location in JSON format and try to ingest it myself", the following python code exposed None Types in my PCollection rows:         json_formatted = extracted_text | 'convertToJSON' >> beam.Map(json.dumps). 2) wasn't really possible since there were only a few edge cases in a massive dataset that took 5 hours to process on 1000 CPUs. thanks for your input